# Muting sound output when using Mic - Audio Web API

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I've created a canvas visualisation that responds to sound recorded through a device's microphone.
All is well and good, however all sound picked up by the mic is played back through the speakers, and I get horrible feedback.

I've tried setting a `gainNode to 0`, but it's not working.
I know I'm missing something, but i can't figure it out.

Here's my code.

```
let getSound = (stream) => {
    const audioCtx = new AudioContext();

    gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
            
    mic = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    mic.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.gain.value = 0;

    analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = 512;
    const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
    const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);
    mic.connect(analyser);
            
    analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
}
```

Comment: I fixed this by removing all references to audioCtx.destination... since I was trying to mute sound and gainNode wasn't working I thought I may as well just not pass the sound to a destination in the first place, since I'm already analysing the data in dataArray for my visualisation.

I'm still curious as to why setting a gain value wasn't working... but for now I found a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph you made looks as follows:

```
mic > gainNode > destination
mic > analyser > destination
```

If you want to level the signal with the gainNode you could chain all the nodes to end up with a graph like this:

```
mic > analyser > gainNode > destination
```

But as you already mentioned the analyser doesn't have to be connected to the destination if you're just interested in the data. Therefore the following graph should work:

```
mic > analyser
```

Comment: Thank you! This really helped. I think I assumed that because my gainNode was connected to my mic it would get muted. Seeing it in this way however makes it really clear. I've given it a test and it works!

gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
mic = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
mic.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
gainNode.gain.value = 0;